# spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams does not consume messages from kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am trying to consume messages from a topic in Kafka via a simple Spring boot application via the spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams library.

I am following the documentation here - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/kafka-streams.adoc

My code is as below:
    package co.zip.poc.springbootkafkakotlin

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import java.util.function.Consumer


@SpringBootApplication
class SpringBootKafkaConsumer {

  @Bean
  fun process(): Consumer<KStream<Any, Any>> {
    println("=======================> Creating a consumer for reading stuff<=====================")
    return Consumer { input -> input.foreach { key, value ->
      println("============key = $key")
      println("===========value = $value")
    }}
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  runApplication<SpringBootKafkaConsumer>(*args)
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: customer-balance
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              application:
                id: customer-balance
      bindings:
        process_in:
          destination: "dbserver1.inventory.customers"

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.kafka.config: trace
```

I have my local kafka running on port 9092. I am able to consume messages via the kafka console consumer -

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --from-beginning \
    --property print.key=true \
    --topic dbserver1.inventory.customers
```

The above produces 4 messages on the console. But when I run the spring boot app, I don't get anything printed for the key = .. and value = print messages.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's an issue with Hoxton.RC1. 
When I updated spring cloud dependencies to Hoxton.M3 it started working fine.

Comment: Could you link to a specific issue?